# Update next value (quarter) based on previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that looks like this:

| rowNum | date | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-10 | Q4 |
| 2 | 2023-09-14 | NULL |
| 3 | 2023-05-14 | NULL |
| 4 | 2023-01-14 | NULL |
| 5 | 2022-12-10 | NULL |
| 6 | 2022-09-14 | NULL |
| 7 | 2022-05-14 | NULL |
| 8 | 2022-01-14 | NULL |

I only have the quarter populated for 1 row. The rest are NULL.
I would like to update the quarters based on the original quarter.
So I would like to update quarter of rowNum 2 to be Q3, rowNum 3 to be Q2, and rowNum 4 to be Q1.

So in the end, I would like to have my table to be:

| rowNum | date | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-10 | Q4 |
| 2 | 2023-09-14 | Q3 |
| 3 | 2023-05-14 | Q2 |
| 4 | 2023-01-14 | Q1 |
| 5 | 2022-12-10 | Q4 |
| 6 | 2022-09-14 | Q3 |
| 7 | 2022-05-14 | Q2 |
| 8 | 2022-01-14 | Q1 |

In SQL, how would I be able to update the next row by the previous value, and do a basic logic/case (instead of just incrementing, for example).

The logic would be:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN [t1].[quarter] = 'Q1' THEN 'Q4'
        WHEN [t1].[quarter] = 'Q2' THEN 'Q1'
        WHEN [t1].[quarter] = 'Q3' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN [t1].[quarter] = 'Q4' THEN 'Q3'
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

#### Edit - after answer provided

I'm actually trying to do this in an automatic way. For example, in this example, I have the original quarter as Q4. However, if I have another set of dates, the only quarter populated could be anything (Q1, Q2, Q3, or Q4).

Comment: You could definitely do this, but will you have quarters that don't follow the normal definition? From the sample it looks like the normal {1: Jan-March, 2: April - June, 3: July-Sept, 4: Oct - Dec}. If you have consecutive values '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-02' do you really want '2023-01-02' being mapped to Q2?

Comment: HI @Error_2646! Thanks for the reply. 

Yeah, in my dataset, my assumption is that I have one row per quarter. Meaning each year I should only have 4 rows. So I would not see 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-02. It would always have 4 dates per year.

Comment: So, why not just calculate the quarter from the month and disregard previous rows

Comment: Hey @siggemannen! Thanks for your reply - so unfortunately, I can't do that. The sample was just 1 example. There are cases where a date 2023-01-01 may point to the Q4 report, and not the Q1 report, for example. So I would need to know the correct quarter of 1 date, and then can work backwards.

Hope that answers your question - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [`case-expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) on the `rowNum` column not on the `quarter` column using the modulo (`%`) math function to achieve what you want:

```
UPDATE
  quarters
SET
  quarter = CASE
    WHEN rowNum % 4 = 1 THEN 'Q4'
    WHEN rowNum % 4 = 2 THEN 'Q3'
    WHEN rowNum % 4 = 3 THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN rowNum % 4 = 0 THEN 'Q1'
    ELSE NULL
  END;
```

[**`DB_FIDDLE`**](https://dbfiddle.uk/i6ssfdoa)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I have more than just 4 rows. So let's say I have 5 years of rows (i.e. 4x5 = 20 rows). I can't just do rowNum = 2, etc. I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That definitely works for this particular use case. Sorry to add on with another scenario (I'll update the question also...). So in the sample, I had my original quarter as Q4. But for another use case, it may be Q3, or Q2, etc. Would it be possible to not hard code the 'Q_' in the SQL? 

So for example, I have another set of dates where my original quarter is Q3. I wouldnt want to update my SQL each time. Thanks, but your answer worked for the question I had asked initially!

Comment: @ToddM you can't keep changing the scope of the question... and why not have a go yourself now you have a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

You *should* have asked a new question, rather than accepting one then providing another that does something different. Anyway, this is what you are looking for, if you need a solution to work with any starting quarter.

It uses the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) analytic function to get the starting value which is then added to the existing row number. Then a case expression determines which quarter it should be.

```
with cte as (
  select *
    , first_value(substring(Quarter, 2, 1)) over (order by RowNum) + RowNum AdjustedRowNum
  from Quarters
)
update cte set Quarter = 
  case AdjustedRowNum % 4
    when 1 then 'Q4'
    when 2 then 'Q3'
    when 3 then 'Q2'
    when 0 then 'Q1'
  end;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jr8t-Ht1)

Comment: Hello! Just following up from the holidays. Thanks for your answer! 
Looking at this, I was not able to get this to work for all starting quarters, I had to update the solution to look like this: 
If it's an even number (Q2, Q4) then: 1 = Q4, 2 = Q3, 3 = Q2, 0 = Q1. 
If it's an odd number (Q1, Q3) then: 1 = Q2, 2 = Q1, 3 = Q4, 0 = Q3.

Answer (score -1):

I set @XM01 - stands with Palestine as the main answer as that was the original question. Thanks for the help!

In the end, I did it in a more programatic way (cause that's what I'm more used to unfortunately). I know it's not the most optimal way, but it seems to do what is required.

Essentially, for each "set" of dates, I get the @originalQuarter. Then I use a while loop and update the quarters based on the previous date. The main issue I was facing was that I could not seem to get the previous quarter, so in the end, this was the way I finished it. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
DECLARE @originalQuarter VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @maxRecords INT, @counter INT = 2;
SELECT @maxRecords = MAX(rowNum) FROM #Temp;
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN

    SET @originalQuarter =
    CASE
        WHEN @originalQuarter = 'Q1' THEN 'Q4'
        WHEN @originalQuarter = 'Q2' THEN 'Q1'
        WHEN @originalQuarter = 'Q3' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN @originalQuarter = 'Q4' THEN 'Q3'
    END;

    UPDATE [#Temp]
    SET [quarter] = @originalQuarter
    WHERE [rowNum] = @counter;

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;

    IF @counter > @maxRecords
        BREAK

END
```

Comment: You should almost never need a loop in SQL - SQL is set based and you have to learn to think in a set based way for an optimal solution.